# Cannot install IE11 on Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: installation, internet-explorer-11, windows-embedded-7

I have downloaded the 'full' installer for IE11 (IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe).

The page here lists prerequisties that are required to install IE11: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2847882

I have installed all of the updates on this page that are applicable to WES7. When I run the installer, it tries to do some stuff, then comes up saying

`Internet Explorer needs an update before installing. Go online and install the required update, then return to the Internet Explorer installation page and run setup again.`

When I click the `Get Update` button, surprise surprise, it directs me to the previous page I linked! The one with the list of updates I've already installed!

How can I install IE11 on WES7?

Edit:

Even in IE11_main.log file, it says it is trying to download 3 update packages that are already installed.

The actual log details:

```
00:21.279: INFO:    Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15CA.tmp\KB2670838_amd64.CAB /quiet /norestart
00:35.350: INFO:    Process exit code 0x800B0100 (-2146762496) [No signature was present in the subject. ]
00:35.350: ERROR:   Error installing prerequisite file (C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15CA.tmp\KB2670838_amd64.CAB): 0x800b0100 (2148204800)
00:35.381: INFO:    PauseOrResumeAUThread: Successfully resumed Automatic Updates.
01:02.947: INFO:    Link clicked, opening URL in new window:'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299206'
01:03.009: INFO:    Setup exit code: 0x00009C57 (40023) - Prerequisites failed to install.
```

Comment: In an elevated command prompt type WMIC  QFE  LIST  FULL and hit enter, be sure those hotfixes are in the generated list.

Comment: Unfortunately that returns `No Instance(s) Available.` I may not have some required package in WES7 that allows this to enumerate update packages or something. The updates are listed in `Programs and Features` Windows Update list.

Comment: They can show up in the programs list but not be installed properly, I would try to reinstall all of them just to check they installed properly.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, for now I've edited in the actual log information.

Comment: Actually, that particular update it's failing on `KB2670838_amd64.CAB` isn't actually an applicable update for WES7...

Comment: Yes but IE11 needs it, there is the problem...

Comment: Right but that's an M$ problem. That package is meant for a full install of Windows 7, not an Embedded version, so the installer is clearly not correctly identifying which packages are suitable for the OS its running on. I've asked on M$ forums as well to see what they say